# On assigning array: "PHP Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered"

Tags: php, arrays, string, numeric, notice

I get this error:

> PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in
>   [...]/model.php on line 205

In this PHP code:

```
   [...]

   echo 'var_dump($i):' . "\n";
   var_dump($i);

   echo 'var_dump($wawiData[$i][\'date\']):' . "\n";
   var_dump($wawiData[$i]['date']);

   $accRecords[] = array(
    'date' => $wawiData[$i]['date'],  # this is line 205
    'description' => $wawiData[$i]['inv-recipient'],
    'field1' => $wawiData[$i]['inv-no'],
    'account' => $account,
    'contra-account' => $wawiData[$i]['client-no'],
    'amount' => $wawiData[$i]['amount'] * -1,  # this is line 210
    'country-code' => $country,
    'rec-type' => $wawiData[$i]['rec-type'],
    'company' => $wawiData[$i]['company'],
    'name' => $wawiData[$i]['name'],
    'freeze' => 0,
    'inv-link' => 'BEDI "' . $guids[$wawiData[$i]['inv-no']] . '"'
   );
  }
 }
 return $accRecords;
}  # end of method
```

Output on console:

```
var_dump($i):
int(0)
var_dump($wawiData[$i]['date']):
string(10) "08.01.2018"
PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in [...]/model.php on line 205
```

I found lots of posts about this *PHP Notice*, but all were about code using `date()` and other functions with malformed parameters.

However, I can't see how this relates to me simply assigning a perfectly fine `string` to an `array` using a perfectly fine `int` as index.

Can anyone explain to me what causes the *PHP Notice*? (line 205 is marked in the code above)

Thanks!

P.S.

```
var_dump($wawiData[$i]):
array(10) {
  ["inv-no"]=>
  string(11) "RE2018-6677"
  ["date"]=>
  string(10) "08.01.2018"
  ["amount"]=>
  string(5) "93,79"
  ["client-no"]=>
  string(5) "12881"
  ["inv-recipient"]=>
  string(27) "(...)"
  ["company"]=>
  string(27) "(...)"
  ["name"]=>
  string(13) "(...)"
  ["rec-type"]=>
  int(2)
  ["country"]=>
  string(11) "Deutschland"
  ["country-code"]=>
  string(2) "DE"
}
```

Comment: Could you paste the output of `var_dump($wawiData[$i]);` please?

Comment: Also, I assume you are within a loop. Try putting `break` in immediatley after you finish adding to `$accRecords`, this will tell you if the problem exists in `$wawiData[0]` or in a higher index by whether or not the error persists.

Comment: You're 2000% sure the error is produced in *that* line? When removing that line, the error vanishes too? You're sure you've caught the correct value using `var_dump`? Can you reproduce this with a minimal example?

Comment: @Scoots, the method ends right after adding to `$accRecords` (see extended snippet above). Should I still add `break` afterwards?

Comment: @deceze if I comment out line 205 I get the same error for line 206. So you seem to be on to something there. I still have no clue. I'm pretty sure about the `var_dump()`. How would you reduce this to a minimal example?

Comment: `$wawiData[$i]['amount'] * -1` with `93,79` couldn't be the issue ? try to replace your `,` by `.`, i'm pretty sure your error will leave

Comment: Can you create some `$wawiData = array(...)` literal that reproduces the same issue? Something you can copy and paste here that we could run that would produce that error?

Comment: @MacBooc you nailed it! Thanks! I commented out the 'amount' line (which is line 210??) and even re-added 'date' line 205 and the notice is gone. Not sure why the PHP interpreter gave me the wrong line number though?!

Comment: @Markus looks like the error code line was provide for the entire array entry, not for the line where the entry blocked actually

Comment: @MacBooc but then it should be line 204, right? Also, would you like to post your solution as an answer below, so we can vote for it?

Comment: to me no, i can't explain why it starts at the begining instead of the line of the probleme, but there isn't any problem to create the array in a first place

Comment: @Markus i don't need upvote by the way, glad i could help you, you can valid your own, but you should explain a bit more why it doesn't work

Comment: PHP can be pretty bad at reporting correct line numbers. If I had to guess why this one was failing, I'd suggest it's because you're using different line endings to what the server is expecting. Windows typically uses `\r\n` while *nix uses `\n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Comment by MacBooc:*
>   `$wawiData[$i]['amount'] * -1` with `93,79` couldn't be the issue? try to replace your `,` by `.`, i'm pretty sure your error will leave

Kudos to @MacBooc for this answer!

Elaboration:

The *PHP Notice* is triggered because I tried to multiply the value `93,79` by `-1`. This causes the notice, as PHP expects a `.` (period) as decimal separator and therefore does not like the `,` (comma - a.k.a. German decimal separator).

**Additional confusion was caused by the fact, that PHP claimed the notice was caused in line 205, though is was actually caused in line 210.**

I added the following lines before line 204:

```
# remove possible thousands separators
$amount = str_replace('.', '', $wawiData[$i]['amount']);
# change decimal separator from ',' to '.' and mulitply by -1
$amount = str_replace(',', '.', $amount) * -1;
# change decimal separator back from '.' to ','
$amount = str_replace('.', ',', $amount);
```

My new code for line 210:

```
'amount' => $amount,
```

Comment: Is there any chance the amount will contain a thousands seperator?

Comment: @Scoots thanks for pointing this out. There is no thousands separator in my data. But I fixed it anyway in the answer.

Comment: As an alternative to a bunch of `str_replace` calls, you may want to consider using [NumberFormatter::parse](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parse.php)